# Comparing two objects to get percentage

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way I can do this using array.map()

I have two lists of locations (WOL, SYD, MEL, etc), one of which has the total count of sites with all devices as children in each location, and the other which just has devices which are in error.

I need to find the percentage of devices in error per site, against the total number of devices per site.

Is there a way I can do this using uniqueSitesCount.map(...)? I've been looking through documentation throughout the weekend and trying to figure out before asking on here, but have so far failed.

`uniqueSitesCountNotOk` - array of locations with only devices which are in Error added to the 'devices' sub-array:

```
[ { site: 'CBR',
    devices: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },
  { site: 'MEL',
    devices: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },
  { site: 'SYD', devices: [] },
  { site: 'WOL', devices: [] } ]
```

`uniqueSitesCount` - array of locations with all objects

```
[ { site: 'CBR',
    devices: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },
  { site: 'MEL',
    devices: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },
  { site: 'SYD', devices: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },
  { site: 'WOL', devices: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] } ]
```

Function:

EDIT: `uniqueSitesCount[i].count` to `uniqueSitesCount[i].devices.length` for clarity

```
var getSiteErrorPercentage = function(uniqueSitesCount, uniqueSitesCountNotOk) {
    for (var i = 0; i < uniqueSitesCount.length; i++) {
        if (uniqueSitesCountNotOk[i].devices.length > 0) {
            console.log(`${uniqueSitesCount[i].site} - ${(uniqueSitesCountNotOk[i].devices.length / uniqueSitesCount[i].devices.length* 100).toFixed(2)}%`)
        } else {
            console.log(uniqueSitesCount[i].site + ' - 0%')
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well `map` is for mapping, IOW: it will return something, your code doesn't returning anything, but just console logs.  Instead you might be thinking of `forEach` instead.  And the answer is yes.

Comment: Is there a reason to use map? it seems like it would be easier to use filter with find in the callback. Although it's hard to help with [object] to work off of tbh.

Comment: Do you just need to count the number of objects in the devices array, or do each of those objects have a number you need to count?

Comment: @Keith, it will be returning the percentages, currently just using Console.Log() while testing

Comment: @DLowther - I'm not just filtering. I already have one array filtered to only have devices in error. What I want to do is show the percentage of devices in error vs total devices

Comment: @Mark_M I need to  show the percentage of devices in error per location vs total devices per location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider quickly looping through `uniqueSitesCount` to make an object that directly maps sites to the count of objects. Something like:

```
var uniqueSitesCount = [ 
    { site: 'CBR', devices: [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[] ] },
    { site: 'MEL', devices: [[],[],[],[],[] ] },
    { site: 'SYD', devices: [[],[],[],[],[] ] },
    { site: 'WOL', devices: [[],[],[],[],[] ] } 
]

var counts =  uniqueSitesCount.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    acc[cur.site] = cur.devices.length
    return acc
}, {})
```

Counts looks like:

```
{ CBR: 11, MEL: 5, SYD: 5, WOL: 5 }
```

With that you can map over your errors and create an array with percentages like:

```js
var uniqueSitesCount = [ 
    { site: 'CBR', devices: [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[] ] },
    { site: 'MEL', devices: [[],[],[],[],[] ] },
    { site: 'SYD', devices: [[],[],[],[],[] ] },
    { site: 'WOL', devices: [[],[],[],[],[] ] } 
]

var uniqueSitesCountNotOk = [ 
    { site: 'CBR', devices: [ [], [], [], [], [], [] ] },
    { site: 'MEL', devices: [ [], [], [], [], [] ] },
    { site: 'SYD', devices: [] },
    { site: 'WOL', devices: [] } 
]

var counts =  uniqueSitesCount.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    acc[cur.site] = cur.devices.length
    return acc
}, {})

var percents = uniqueSitesCountNotOk.map(item => {
    var n = item.devices.length / counts[item.site] * 100
    return {site:item.site, count: n}
})

console.log(percents)
```

Alternatively, you could avoid the count object, but then you'd have to search the `uniqueSitesCount` object every time:

```
var percents = uniqueSitesCountNotOk.map(item => {
   var site = uniqueSitesCount.find(i => i.site === item.site )
   var n = item.devices.length / site.devices.length * 100
   return {site:item.site, count: n}
})
```

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated :)

Still new to the functional aspects of JS and the newer ES2015 syntax, so trying to get my head around map, reduce and filter at the moment. Cheers!